# Can a report's filename contain special symbols such as "$" and "%"

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is it possible to name a report something like, "People Who Owe Me $10" or "Discount % Report"?  I initially was able to name a report with a $ sign, but I was then unable to deploy it.  However, I changed it to say "Dollars" instead and it successfully deployed.

Is it possible to have a report filename that contains "$" and "%" symbols?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could, this is bad practice. Try to keep it `A-z 0-9 -_`